# Generic Bind with Guice

Tags: java, guice

I trying to build a simple lib for persistence with guice persist and some other things.

I already have a `AbstractDao<T>`, that I can easily extend and bind the concrete implementation like a boss.

But, I want a kind of GenericDao, like this:

```
public abstract class GenericDao<T extends Bean> {


@Inject
private Provider<EntityManager> emp;

protected EntityManager em() {
    return emp.get();
}

public AbstractDao() {
}

protected abstract Class<T> clazz();
// ....
```

And if I will have just the CRUD (implemented in abstract dao) in for some bean, I want to inject `GenericDao<SomeBean>` like a boss.

So, I started to try some hacks, and get the following:

```
public abstract class AbstractPersistentModule extends AbstractModule {

    protected <T extends Bean> LinkedBindingBuilder<T> bindGenericDao(final Class<T> clazz) {
       return bind(
               new TypeLiteral<GenericDao<T>>(){}
       )./* what the hell can I do here? */;
    }
}
```

If I can make it work, I'll be able to do a simple:

```
bindGenericDao(Pessoa.class);
```

Someone know a way to do that?

Comment: It's not clear where the real implementation comes from. Could you clarify the question?

Comment: that's the problem, in that case, the real impl would just provide the `Class<T>`, so, I trying to made it in execution time somehow...

Comment: But how could your binder know which class extends `GenericDao<T>` in a concrete way? That's my point... even if you knew `T` completely here, we still wouldn't know about an implementation.

Comment: I was thinking if I can create a inner-class and a child injector or something like this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [post](http://jamolkhon.blogspot.com/2012/07/generic-typesafe-dao-with-guice-and.html) for a working implementation.

Answer (score 1):

With a lot of hacks, I finally managed it to work. Please, take a look and tell me what you think: https://github.com/namekusei/persistence/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/namekusei/inject/AbstractPersistentModule.java

Answer (score 1):

I remember that Weld is another way to do it, you can use the @InjectionPoint's to say the type of injected element..

```
class Foo {
   @Inject
   private GenericDAO<Employee> dao;
   //...
}

..
@Produces
public GenericDAO<T> createDaoInstances(InjectionPoint type){
   return new GenericDAO(type.getMember().getSomeThing());
}

public GenericDAO<T>{
   //..
   public GenericDAO<T>(EntityManager em){
   //...
}
```

}

I think this is a more interesting, just because you can better separate the binding between components and layers.

Comment: If i not mistaken, guice does not have a `InjectionPoint` behavior like this... this is sad, a implementation like your example will be much more simple and clean... thanks anyway

Comment: Yes caarlos0, but you cannot create an producer factory for EntityManager and specify on DAO constructors..would be more elegant and simple.